Convert interfaces to netplan with complex routing
I have the interfaces configuration below from my 18.04 ubuntu server. It has 2 network interfaces that are on different VLANs of the same network. I'm now migrating the server to a new one with ubuntu 24.04 which uses netplan.. How can I convert the config below to netplan? I've tried some suggestions online but have found nothing definitive so far...
    # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
    # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
    
    source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
    
    # The loopback network interface
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback
    
    # The primary network interaface
    #auto eno1
    allow-hotplug eno1
    iface eno1 inet static
     address 10.10.99.3
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     network 10.10.99.0
     broadcast 10.10.99.255
     gateway 10.10.99.254
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
     dns-nameservers 10.10.1.3 10.10.1.1 10.5.1.1 10.6.1.4
     dns-search mgmonitor02.central2.local central2.local
     post-up ip route add 10.0.0.0/16 eno1 src 10.10.99.3 table rt1
     post-up ip route add default via 10.10.99.254 dev eno1 table rt1
     post-up ip rule add from 10.10.99.3/32 table rt1
     post-up ip rule add to 10.10.99.3/32 table rt1
    
    
    allow-hotplug ens6
    iface ens6 inet static
     address 10.0.0.7
     netmask 255.255.0.0
     network 10.0.0.0
     broadcast 10.0.255.255
     # gateway 10.0.0.1
     # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
     dns-nameservers 10.10.1.3 10.10.1.1 10.5.1.1 10.6.1.4
     dns-search mgmonitor02.central2.local central2.local
     post-up ip route add 10.0.0.0/16 dev ens6 src 10.0.0.7 table rt2
     post-up ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev ens6 table rt2
     post-up ip rule add from 10.0.0.7/32 table rt2
     post-up ip rule add to 10.0.0.7/32 table rt2
     post-up ip route add 10.0.0.4 via 10.0.0.1 dev ens6

I tried to convert using some exapmple configs that found online but I always get errors.... This is my current netplan:
    # This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
    # to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
    # network configuration capabilities, write a file
    # /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
    # network: {config: disabled}
        network:
          ethernets:
            ens18:
                addresses:
                - 10.0.0.7/16
                nameservers:
                    addresses:
                    - 10.10.1.3
                    - 10.10.1.2
                    - 10.5.1.1
                    - 10.6.1.4
                    - 8.8.8.8
                    search:
                    - central2.local
                routes:
                -   to: default
                    via: 10.0.0.1
            ens19:
                addresses:
                - 10.10.99.3/24
                nameservers:
                    addresses:
                    - 10.10.1.3
                    - 10.10.1.2
                    - 10.5.1.1
                    - 10.6.1.4
                    - 8.8.8.8
                    search:
                    - central2.local
                routes:
                -   to: default
                    via: 10.10.99.254
        version: 2

